# Is this a proof of equivalence relation?

Tags: proof-writing, equivalence-relations

I want to prove $a \equiv b\;(\text{mod} \;n)$ is an equivalence relation then would it be ok to write,

Reflexive as, for all $a$, $a \equiv a\;(\text{mod} \;n)$

Symmetric as, $a \equiv b\;(\text{mod} \;n)$  which implies $b \equiv a\;(\text{mod} \;n)$

Transitive as if $a \equiv b\;(\text{mod} \;n)$ and $b \equiv c\;(\text{mod} \;n)$ this implies $a \equiv c\;(\text{mod} \;n)$

I dont know if this has actually proved equivalence. Also the set on which this relatiton acts on was not specified so for reflexivity is it ok to say for all $a$. Thanks.

Comment: It's fine. ${}$

Comment: Well, if you **really** proved all those three, then yes: you've already prove it is an equiv. relation.

Comment: @James: Use the definition $a \equiv b\;(\text{mod}\;n)$ iff $n$ divides $a-b$ to show this is true, otherwise it is look like a meaning of reflexive, symmetric and transitive

Comment: Hint: If $a\equiv b\mod n$, $n\;|\;a-b$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not ok, because what you did is just wrote what you have to prove, not really proved it. First of all, the relation is on $\mathbb{Z}$. Next, what is the relation? $a\equiv b$(mod $n$) by definition means that $n|(a-b)$. So that is the relation: $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ are related if $n$ divides $a-b$. Now you have to prove it is an equivalence relation. For example, it is reflexive because for each $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $a-a=0$ and obviously $n|0$ because $0\times n=0$. Now try to show the other properties.

Comment: can you prove the symetry part using the modulus so if n divides a-b then it divides the modulus of that which is the modulus b-a and if n divides that then n divides b-a?

Comment: If you show that $n$ divides a number if and only if $n$ divides its modulus then yes. But I think a straight proof is easier: $n|(a-b)$ means there is $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $nc=a-b$. Multiply by $(-1)$ to get $(-c)n=b-a$ and hence $n|(b-a)$.

Comment: For transivity i wrote out three equations using the idea that if n divides (a-b) then for some integer say c you can build an equation. i did some rearanging and got the final equation with the constant in terms of the other two and so its transitive, is this ok? Thanks

Comment: If $cn=a-b$ and $dn=b-c$ then $a-c=(a-b)+(b-c)=cn+dn=(c+d)n$, so $n|(a-c)$. That's it. If you did something like that then you got it right.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not ok. You just *claimed* that all three assertions are true without a trace of evidence. Therefore, you proved nothing.